# I am running the code below in python and getting the error 'AttributeError: 'QgridWidget' object has no attribute 'to_excel''

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to use to excel function using the code below. I am getting the error `df.to_excel('dataset1.xlsx')`

Below is the code.

```
df=qgrid.show_grid(data)
df.to_excel('dataset1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please add error too.

Answer (score 0):

`qgrid.show_grid()` returns a `QgridWidget` instance. You can access the underlying dataframe using the `df` attribute:

```
grid = qgrid.show_grid(data)
grid.df.to_excel('dataset1.xlsx')
```